# Navigate to a Master details Page in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hello guys I am navigating to a master details page with this code:-

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MasterPage_Jobseeker());
```

But it is showing the back button instead the hamburger menu.

What should I do now?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the back button off on the NavigationPage.

```
var masterPage = new MasterPage_Jobseeker();
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(masterPage, false);
await Navigation.PushAsync(masterPage);
```

Although, I think if you're navigating to a `MasterDetailPage` you probably should be replacing the entire application main page with it to control the rest of your navigation from your MasterDetailPage.

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterPage_Jobseeker();
```

Comment: I have already tried to reset the master page.but in that case no navbar is coming in the page.
i am setting the Mainpage to the Masterpage.

Comment: You have to add a `NavigationPage` to the DetailPage of your MasterDetailPage